# Merging text files in csh while preserving place rows

Tags: shell, csh, mks

I have about 100 text files with two columns that I would like to merge into a single file in a c shell script by using factor "A".

For example, I have file A that looks like this

**A B1** 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

 

 
and File B looks like this

**A B2** 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

5 300 

6 400

I want the final file C to look like this:

**A B1 B2** 

1 100 100 

2 200 200 

3 300 300 

4 400 400 

5 300 

6 400

The `cat` function only puts the files on top of one another and pastes them into file C. I would like to put the data next to each other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

to meet your exact spec, this will work. If the spec changes, you'll need to play with this some,

```
paste -d' ' factorA factorB \
| awk 'NF==4||NF==3{print $1, $2, $3} NF==2{print$1, $2}' \
> factorC

# note, no spaces or tabs after each of the contintuation chars `\` at end of lines!
```

**output**

```
$ cat factorC
A B1 B2 
1 100 100 
2 200 200 
3 300 300 
4 400 400 
5 300 
6 400
```

Not sure how you get `bold` headers to "trasmit" thru unix pipes. ;->

Recall that `awk` programs all have a basic underlying structure, i.e.

```
awk 'pattern{action}' file
```

So `pattern` can be a range of lines, a reg-exp, an expression (`NF==4`), missing, or a few other things.

The `action` is what happens when the pattern is matched. This is more traditional looking `code`.

If no `pattern` specified, then `action` applies to all lines read. If no `action` is specfied, but the `pattern` matches, then the line is printed (without further ado).

`NF` means `N`umberOf`F`ields in the current line, so `NF==2` will only process line with 2 fields (the trailing records in factorB).

The `||` is a logical `OR` operator, so that block will only process records, where the number of fields is `3 OR 4`. Hopefully, the `print` statements are self-explanatory.

The `,` separating `$1,$2,$3` (for example) is the syntax that converts to awk's internal variable `OFS`, which is `OutputFieldSeparator`, which can be assigned like `OFS="\t"` (to give an OFS of tab char), or as in this case, we are not specifying a value, so we're getting the default value for OFS, which is the space char (`" "`) (no quotes!)

IHTH